# How do I make sure that my label is always centered on the line?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uibezierpath

I tried to take the coordinates of the LinePath.bounds.Max and line Path.bounds.Maxi , but it does not give the desired result

```
enter code here
private func addLine(start:CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: start)
    linePath.addLine(to: end)
    line.path = linePath.cgPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    line.lineWidth = 4

   distanceLabel.text = String(distanceForLabel)
    distanceLabel.textColor = .black
    distanceLabel.frame = CGRect(x: linePath.bounds.midX,
                                 y: line.bounds.midY,
                                 width: linePath.bounds.width / 2,
                                 height: 20)
    uiImageView.addSubview(distanceLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your are setting the `y` value for the label's frame to:

```
y: line.bounds.midY
```

but it should be:

```
y: linePath.bounds.midY
```

However, your frame code puts the **top-left corner** of the label at the midpoint of the line.

If you want the **center** of the label to be centered on the line, use this for your label's frame:

```
distanceLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: linePath.bounds.width / 2.0, height: 20.0)
distanceLabel.center = CGPoint(x: linePath.bounds.midX, y: linePath.bounds.midY)
```